# [ERROR]: PostConfirmation invocation failed due to error Socket timeout while invoking Lambda function

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-nodejs

I've been trying to use post confirmation lambda trigger function to add userdata to the dynamodb, but i've been getting the error `PostConfirmation invocation failed due to error Socket timeout while invoking Lambda function` immediately the user confirms the registration.

Is there any configuration i have to make to solve this issue?

Here is my lambda function

```
const documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

const _tableName = process.env.USERTABLE;

export async function handler(event, context) {

  if (!event?.request?.userAttributes?.sub) {
    console.log("no sub found");
    return;
  }
  const date = new Date();

  const _userItem = {
    id: { S: event?.request?.userAttributes?.sub },
    createdAt: { S: date.toISOString() },
    email: { S: event?.request?.userAttributes?.email },
    fullName: { S: event?.request?.userAttributes?.name },
    phoneNumber: { S: event?.request?.userAttributes?.phone_number },
    profileImageUri: { S: event?.request?.userAttributes?.picture },
    updatedAt: { S: date.toISOString() },
    _lastChangedAt: { N: date.getTime().toString() },
    _version: { N: "1" },
    __typename: { S: "User" },
  };
  const params = {
    userItem: _userItem,
    TableName: _tableName,
  };

  documentClient.put(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else console.log(data);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the PostConfirmation Lambda trigger with Cognito, you need to add a third argument `callback` (you can name it whatever you want) in your handler signature, and call it once your business logic has been executed, e.g:

```
documentClient.put(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else console.log(data);
    callback(null, event);
});
```

See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-post-confirmation.html#aws-lambda-triggers-post-confirmation-example) for more details.